# UTF-8 without BOM in php files

Tags: byte-order-mark

on every page on my site see these symbols " ï»¿ï»¿  "
idon't know why some people suggested to put charset=\"UTF-8\" at the top of the page
but also didn't work
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your code files in Notepad++ and then selecting Encoding > Encode in UTF-8 without BOM.